# where to close the auto syntax prompt?

Tags: settings

when I code in vs code, it always appear the auto syntax prompt below, where can I close this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHC3H.png)

I tried lots of ways in vs code settings, but nothing changed, the release I upgraded recently was 1.84.2. Or you can tell me which plugin can solve my question? Thanks.